# En un TabbedActivity con un ViewPager los ListView me quedan cortados por abajo

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo un `TabbedActivity` con tres `Fragments` de tipo lista pero me quedan cortados por abajo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado de todo pero no sé que hacer.

Este es el layout del `TabbedActivity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.domain.app.TabbedActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Y dentro del `ViewPager` cargo el `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Muchas gracias!

**EDITO**: La solución que me ha funcionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35010886/in-a-tabbed-activity-with-viewpager-the-listview-appears-cut-from-the-bottom/35025680#35025680

Comment: ¿Has probado introduciendo un `ScrollView` en tu `ViewPager`?, recuerda que para que funcione correctamente tienes que utilizar el atributo `android:fillViewport` en el `ScrollView` para que funcione bien.

Comment: Sí que hay scroll. Lo que me pasa es que el último element aparece cortado por abajo. Es como si el ScrollView estuviera fuera del marco...

Comment: prueba de poner el layout_heigth de listview a wrap_content

Comment: Hace lo mismo con wrap_content que con match_parent...

Comment: @guillemp gracias por hacer referencia a la pregunta que te brindo la solucion, pero si te fijas en el autor de la respuesta veras algo curioso. De echo tambien te publique la respuesta en este hilo y fue donde primero te la deje. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede que este diseño ayude en lo que busca, añadir:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Quedando asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.domain.app.TabbedActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Notas: Se ha suprimido `android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"` para poder hacer las pruebas.

Comment: Gracias Angel. Te lo he marcado como respuesta aceptada aquí también :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad `layout_weight` con un valor de `1`. De esta manera llenará la pantalla:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.domain.app.TabbedActivity">
    ...
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Más información en [Layout Weight](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight).

Comment: Me soluciona la parte de abajo. Ahora me queda cortado por arriba.

Comment: Entonces, estás teniendo algún control extra que te está robando espacio arriba o abajo. Quitaría android:fitsSystemWindows="true".